# JW Player - Only a black screen, sound works

Tags: jwplayer

i have a problem with the JW Player (http://www.longtailvideo.com).

The sounds works but the screen is black. But why?
Hope someone can help me.

**JS**

```
   $('body').append('<div id="mediaplayer"></div>');
    $.getScript('http://player.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer.js', function ()
    {
       jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
         flashplayer: "http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf",
         file: 'http://www.n-tv.de/podcast/mp4/wetter/33sekunden_1105161548.mp4',
     autostart: "true"
    });
       $('#mediaplayer_wrapper').css('z-index','107').css('width','853px').css('height','505px').css('padding','10px').addClass('bg_one').center();
    });
```

**Here is an example**
http://jsfiddle.net/yMh5r/4/

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: From what domain are you running this? Migh be problem with a cross site scripting

Comment: The mp4 file is not on my server. Is this the problem? But why did the sound works?

Answer (score 1):

Check the encoding of your mp4 file - we've had the same issue with our mp4 files in the past, and it was the encoding to blame.  Sorry I don't know exactly what our video guys did to fix it though. :(

Comment: hi, the videos are from an other podcast page, i dont have access. Is there maybe a player which can play that files?

Answer (score 0):

JW Player has support mp4 video only encoded with H.264. 
So, you should try to re-encode your files.
For example you can use VLC for it:

```
cvlc -I dummy -vvv example_input_file.mp4 –sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264, vb=1024, acodec=aac, ab=128, channels=2}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=example_output_file.mp4} vlc:quit
```

VLC has support for re-encoding remote files and can save them to your local directory, too.